# Magento 2 Rest API get Quote Item Custom Option values

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, custom-options, rest-api

Hi I have tried with the magento 2 rest apis

1) `V1/orders/:order-id`

2) `V1/orders/items` with serach filter order id

3) `/V1/carts/:quoteid/items`

The above apis are not returning the Order item custom product attribute values. When i checked the DB i can see the values i entered while add the product to cart in the DB table `quote_item_option`, however i cannot retrieve those values via the api.

Can anyone please help to attain the values with the correct api ?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I know its possible but I don't see documentation.

Comment: @jamil: No still searching for solutions.

Comment: @Zammuuz how do you added the custom product attribute?

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this?